# ASP.NET MVC Bootstrap Project - How to run .cs file with a button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

So I have made a new ASP.NET MVC Project with Bootstrap. I want to run a the following code with the click of a html button: (code for google cloud text to speech)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1;

public class QuickStart
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Instantiate a client
        TextToSpeechClient client = TextToSpeechClient.Create();


        // Set the text input to be synthesized.
        SynthesisInput input = new SynthesisInput
        {
            Text = "Hello, World!"
        };

        // Build the voice request, select the language code ("en-US"),
        // and the SSML voice gender ("neutral").
        VoiceSelectionParams voice = new VoiceSelectionParams
        {
            LanguageCode = "en-US",
            SsmlGender = SsmlVoiceGender.Neutral
        };

        // Select the type of audio file you want returned.
        AudioConfig config = new AudioConfig
        {
            AudioEncoding = AudioEncoding.Mp3
        };

        // Perform the Text-to-Speech request, passing the text input
        // with the selected voice parameters and audio file type
        var response = client.SynthesizeSpeech(new SynthesizeSpeechRequest
        {
            Input = input,
            Voice = voice,
            AudioConfig = config
        });

        // Write the binary AudioContent of the response to an MP3 file.
        using (Stream output = File.Create("sample.mp3"))
        {
            response.AudioContent.WriteTo(output);
            Console.WriteLine($"Audio content written to file 'sample.mp3'");
        }
    }
}
```

Where exactly should I paste the code and how can I link it to run with the button clicked?

Thanks in advance,
Nikola

Comment: Are you trying to run a console application from web application?

Comment: @RajeshG Well.. Yes.

Comment: Can you explain your use case? Why exactly you need to run a console application from a web page? There is no straight forward approach to do this.

Comment: @RajeshG Yes, of course. So I am trying to make a simple text-to-speech website/program with the Google Cloud API, because they have the best human-like voices. I only know HTML and CSS, no previous .NET experience. I just need a UI for the tts program, where I can paste the text and change voices. I searched in google a lot and the way I found to combine the TTS Code and the knowledge I have was this, but as I can see it really isn't :D

Comment: @RajeshG I've read it. The languages on which you can run the program are: c#, Java, Go, Php, Node.js, Python and Ruby

Answer (score 0):

if you want to execute your method from a button on the client side you could try this.

in the cshtml view use:

```
<div>
<a class="btn btn-success" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SomeView" >Execute Method</a>
```

Then in the associated Controller (i am assuming it is "HomeController") use a view to fire off your method and return whatever view you want.  Im not sure if this is exactly what you wanted  hope this helps

```
    public IActionResult SomeView()
    {
        TextToSpeech();
        return View();
    }


public void TextToSpeech()
    {
        // Instantiate a client
        TextToSpeechClient client = TextToSpeechClient.Create();


        // Set the text input to be synthesized.
        SynthesisInput input = new SynthesisInput
        {
            Text = "Hello, World!"
        };

        // Build the voice request, select the language code ("en-US"),
        // and the SSML voice gender ("neutral").
        VoiceSelectionParams voice = new VoiceSelectionParams
        {
            LanguageCode = "en-US",
            SsmlGender = SsmlVoiceGender.Neutral
        };

        // Select the type of audio file you want returned.
        AudioConfig config = new AudioConfig
        {
            AudioEncoding = AudioEncoding.Mp3
        };

        // Perform the Text-to-Speech request, passing the text input
        // with the selected voice parameters and audio file type
        var response = client.SynthesizeSpeech(new SynthesizeSpeechRequest
        {
            Input = input,
            Voice = voice,
            AudioConfig = config
        });

        //// Write the binary AudioContent of the response to an MP3 file.
        //using (System.IO.Stream output = File.Create("sample.mp3"))
        //{
        //    response.AudioContent.WriteTo(output);
        //    Console.WriteLine($"Audio content written to file 'sample.mp3'");
        //}



    }
```

Comment: After that I want to link the text, which the program will convert to audio to be gathered from a html text field, so with the solution you recommended is it going to be possible?